# Differences between document vs $document in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What are the differences between using `document` and `$document` while developing Angular's applications?
I read that it's better to use angular's equivalents like:
`$window` instead of `window` or `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`.

But... why?
I thought `window`, `setTimeout` and `document` are faster because they are native and doesn't need to "pass through" code of Angular framework.

Is it better to use Angular's equivalents instead of native functions, objects from JS?

Comment: Absolutely agree with you.. Yes the native code is faster but the reason I understand is that the new angular developer after you may not understand the native code.. That's why, probably. But I wonder why (or precisely how) people learn Angular without knowing what happens in native code?

Comment: Look what angularJS docs states:
A jQuery or jqLite wrapper for the browser's window.document object.

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout this will help u

Answer (score 9):

By using the angular services for $document and $window you make your code unit test ready.
This dependency injection allows you to use mock versions of $document or $window in your tests.

The performance impact mentioned can be ignored.

Answer (score 7):

`$document` is a jQuery object, `$(document)`.

So basically you should be able to do:

```
$document[0].property = document.property
```

You can look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/sniffer.js#L24) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Following is always true:
$window.document === $document[0]

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular wrapers, bcus it doesn't break the angular synchronization with model->view,

For exmaple, if you use setTimeout you will have to $digest() the scope to refresh the values in the view, if you plan on changing some model values, on the other hand if you use $timeout you don't need to do it bcus the scope will refresh after the function ends